# Best practice for crediting users account with PHP MySQL and paypal express checkout

Tags: php, sql, paypal, currency

I am integrating PayPal Express Checkout API into a digital goods/services website. I worked out all the technical stuff, but now I have a theoretical question - when the transaction is done and I get a confirmation from PayPal, what is the best way to store that acknowledgement from paypal, and credit my user's account?

The `ConfirmPayment()` function in the paypal library returns from paypal with an associative array, including a transaction ID, and acknowledgement that I have the user's money in my business account.

So my plan is, store that transaction ID as a `unique` value in a SQL table, so if the user for example reloads the confirmation page, which would then re-call `ConfirmPayment($token)`, my PHP script won't just credit their account a second time, because the SQL table will return a unique ID error.

How are smart programmers integrating this last payment confirmation into the rest of their application?
THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so:

Keep a full log of all the messages your receive from Paypal. Just the RAW data should be fine. Then beyond that point don't need that much traceability. If anything ever happens you can check the log. This should really never happen, if you need to look at this log a lot to resolve any issues you have a different kind of problem. This is why my suggestion is: don't put too much time into it, but make sure you have traceability (albeit a very crude one).

---

If the user reloads the confirmation page, Paypal will not send you another message. Keep in mind that you should only accept transactions that Paypal has verified. The user should not be able to validate his own transactions by bypassing Paypal.

Comment: Thanks! The reload thing I was playing with is this: After the user confirms payment info on paypal's external website, they are redirected back to my page with a token, so the user gets a url from paypal: `MyPage.com/confirm.php?token=123456789` and that `confirm.php` script calls `ConfirmPayment()` on my end and credits  the user's account. But they have that URL with the token! And everytime they load `confirm.php?token=...` my script will run `ConfirmPayment(token)`

Comment: Yes, this is **not** how you do transaction verification. A user could _guess_ the value of the token and bypass PayPal. PayPal has several verification mechanisms. I've used IPN before, which is a push-model notification system. Paypal send you a message stating which transaction was verified and some extra info like a security hash to verify the data is not tampered with. This is what you should be looking in to.

Comment: Well the `ConfirmPayment()` still sends the token to paypal along with the user's paypal ID and all my API IDs, so I imagine a counterfeit token would return an error from paypal. But I am looking into IPN right now, any time I can take the user out of the equation is +1 :-)